# MATLAB: return both arguments from ISMEMBER when used inside SPLITAPPLY

Tags: matlab, cell-array, split-apply-combine

How can I access both arguments of `ismember` when it is used inside `splitapply`?

`slitapply` only returns scalar values for each group, so in order to compute nonscalar values for each group (as returned by the first argument of `ismemebr`), one has to enclose the anonymous function (in this case `ismember`) inside curly brackets `{}` to return a cell array.

But now, when I provide two output arguments to `splitapply`, I get an error:

`Output argument "varargout{2}" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to
"@(x,y) {ismember(x,y)}"`

**ADD 1**

I can create another function, say, `ismember2cell` which would apply `ismember` and turn outputs into cell arrays:

```
function [a, b] = ismember2cell(x,y)
  [a,b] = ismember(x,y);
  a = {a};
  b = {b};
end
```

but maybe there is a solution which doesn't require this workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potentially faster option is to just do what [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) is already doing under the hood by splitting your data into cell arrays (using functions like [`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html) or [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)) and then using [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply your function across them. Using `cellfun` will allow you to easily capture multiple outputs (such as from [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)). For example:

```
% Sample data:
A = [1 2 3 4 5];
B = [1 2 1 5 5];
G = [1 1 1 2 2];  % Group index

% Group data into cell arrays:
cellA = accumarray(G(:), A(:), [], @(x) {x(:).'});  % See note below about (:).' syntax
cellB = accumarray(G(:), B(:), [], @(x) {x(:).'});

% Apply function:
[Lia, Locb] = cellfun(@ismember, cellA, cellB, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

**NOTE:** My sample data are row vectors, but I had to use the [colon operator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) to reshape them into column vectors when passing them to `accumarray` (it wants columns). Once distributed into a cell array, each piece of the vector would still be a column vector, and I simply wanted to keep them as row vectors to match the original sample data. The syntax `(:).'` is a colon reshaping followed by a [nonconjugate transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html), ensuring a row vector as a result no matter the shape of `x`. In this case I probably could have just used `.'`, but I've gotten into the habit of never assuming what the shape of a variable is.

Comment: Thank you. This looks interesting. Will investigate and come back.

Comment: Could you please explain / point to an explanation of the syntax used in the creation of cell arrays `x(:).'`? In particular, what does the dot `.` do? Thanks

Comment: @Confounded: I added an extra note to the answer. Hope that clears up what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a global solution, but [the accepted answer of this post](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/107354-handles-returning-multiple-outputs#answer_116193) helps me to define a helper function for your problem:

```
function varargout = out2cell(varargin)
[x{1:nargout}]=feval(varargin{:});
varargout = num2cell(x);
```

I think that you may succeed in calling

```
splitapply(@(x,y) out2cell(@ismember, x, y), A, B);
```